# ImapLib How can I limit the number of messages fetched?

Tags: python, imaplib

I have many e-mail messages in the inbox which I am trying to clean up. I am using the following code I found on the net, but it is exceeding the Maxline limit.  I tried increasing imaplib._MAXLINE as suggested in another post, very significantly, but even that is exceeded. How can I modify the code to fetch only say 1000 messages at a time? Additionally, what is the syntax to limit the messages fetched to a given date range? Thank you.

```
def fetch_message(conn, msg_uid ):
    """
    Fetch a specific message uid (not sequential id!) from the given folder;
    return the parsed message. User must ensure that specified
    message ID exists in that folder.
    """
    rv, data = conn.uid('fetch', msg_uid, "(RFC822)")
    if rv != 'OK':
        print ("ERROR fetching message #", msg_uid)
        return {}

    return email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])  # dict-like object
```

Comment: What are you passing for msg_uid?  If it's just a single number, you're only downloading a single message already.

Comment: I changed this as follows to get 100 messages: but it is very slow on Yahoo. At 500 it takes forever. I don't need message detail; I only need the "from". Can you please suggest anything I can do to make this faster? 
    id_list = mail_ids[0].split()   
    first_email_id = int(id_list[0])
    latest_email_id = int(id_list[200])
    for i in range(latest_email_id,first_email_id, -1):   
        rv, data = conn.uid('fetch', msg_uid, "(RFC822)")
        return email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])  # dict-like object

Comment: You can fetch just the headers by changing your item from RFC822 to something like BODY.PEEK[HEADER], instead.  You can even try using BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS(FROM)] (I believe) to get just the FROM.  Or use the `ENVELOPE` item.  Lots of ideas.  You can pass more than one message at a time to fetch (comma separated, or colon ranges)

Comment: Thank you very much.  I appreciate your help. Can you please point me to a resource which helps me learn this library?

Comment: It is a very thing layer over the protocol, so the [RFC reference for IMAP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3501) is your go to-to see how it works.  You can jump to the FETCH and SEARCH sections, which are usually what people are interested in.